# Problems incrementing a field of an object inside an array in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In firestore, i have a collection called `questions` of documents with the following structure

```
{ category : "animals",
topics : [ {title :"habitats", votes: 1}, {title :"pets", votes: 5} ] }
```

I want to build a function that receives `title` as parameter, and increments `votes` by one, with no success.

I am trying things like :

```
const docRef = doc(db, "questions", id);

await updateDoc(docRef, {
        topics: {
          name: topicName,
          vote: increment(1),
        },
      });

//with arrayUnion

await updateDoc(docRef, {
        topics: arrayUnion{
          name: topicName,
          vote: increment(1),
        },
      });
```

But the only thing I do is updating the array replacing the two objects with just a new one, or adding a new object to the two existing ones.

Comment: There is no operator to update an item in an array, only to remove or add complete items. To update an item you will have to: 1. Read the entire array from the document, 2. Update the item in the array in your application code, 3. Write the entire array back to the database

Comment: ok, i understand. Thank you ver much.
Could you give a hint about how that would look with that collection? I am a bit lost at the moment.

Comment: I gave a 3 step way to implement this. If you're stuck at a specific step in that process, the best way to get help is by posting a new question with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the step that you got stuck at.

Comment: Those indications I am sure has to be very helpful for more experienced guys, but with total beginners ... 
Thanks Anyway. To know that what i was trying to do wasn't possible it was helpful. 
In the end , i had to first remove the element from the array with `arrayRemove()` and then add it again with `arrayUnion` , with the updated field. 
Using `batch.commit()` to perform  both operations.